# SharePoint 2010 List Validation not working as expected for DataFormWebPart

Tags: 2010, custom-list, custom-form, validation

I created a custom list and kept the "**Title**" as **unique** and **required**.

- When I use the **ListFormWebPart** in "NewForm.aspx" all the validations **work fine**,  i.e. for required and dulicate entry it shows the validation messages.
- But for **DataFormWebPart**, created via SharePoint Designer 2010 or out of the box for the same list, the **required** validation **works but** the **unique does not** work as expected and throws the asp.net default exception web page showing the following error:
  ***The list item could not be added or updated because duplicate values were found in the following field(s) in the list: [Title]***

**Note:** The ListFormWebPart is the default "NewForm.aspx" and the DataFormWebPart is created by default in the customNewForm.aspx added via SPD 2010

I have not changed anything in the new custom form and i need to make the custom form. Do i need to do any other thing specifically to get this validation working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the problem but came up with a work around for the problem:

Since, i was making a custom form and making changes in that; the validation for uniqueness was not triggering.

So, in the default new form I made all the custom design changes via Jquery rather changing them directly in the form (as **ListFormWebPart** cannot be edited via sharepoint designer) and everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: You could also use a query of the list to check for uniqueness in the form controls as an alternative workaround.